# URL Decode not working for &#8220;

Tags: java, character-encoding

Using the following snippet:

```
String result = URLDecoder.decode("Secretario de Vivienda pide "
                + "ayuda ante &#8220;crisis&#8221; de"
                + " vivienda a precios asequibles", "UTF-8");
```

I would expect the result to be

> Secretario de Vivienda pide ayuda ante “crisis” de vivienda a precios
>   asequibles

However the result remains encoded.

Can anyone point out what is going wrong?

Comment: `&#8220` seems like an HTML entity.

Comment: Maybe you need HTML decode instead of URL decode.

Comment: Lolz, I did have them confused, thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis